# react setState without touching others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Assuming I have an object like below :

```
person : {
    name : "Test",
    surname : "Test",
    age : 40,
    salary : 5000
    currency : "dollar",
    currency_sign : "$",
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want do this

> I will send a post request to link like 'update/currency' which currency will be change with many params and I will update the person object with setState but I don't want to touch others which not comes from response.

```
axios.post('update/currency', {
    currency : 'euro',
    token : '...'
}).then( res => {
    if ( res.response.data.message == 'success' ) {

        res.response.data.params.forEach( (val, index) => {
            // what should i do in here without touching the others
            // forexample params has this props
            // currency
            // currency_sign
            //salary
        });

        // setState to person
        this.setState( ? );
    }
}, err => ... );
```

by the way I'm using redux ... would it help to this ?

I'm using lumen 5.4 in backend and res.response.data.params is json object.

> examle response for res.response.data.params

```
$params = [
    'currency' => [
        'euro'
    ],
    'currency_sign' => [
        '€'
    ],
    'salary' => '10000',
    'salary_pay' => 'monthly',
    'salary_payment' => [
        ['now'],
        ['check|50%', 'cash|50%']
    ]
];
return response()->json($params);
```

Comment: Doing it in Redux way using [Reducers](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html).

Btw, I suggest you take the (course)[https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux]. It's from the creator of redux and it's necessary for Redux beginners.

Comment: i didn't understand the reducers so i don't want to use it . course is not in the link. missing. check the course link please ...

Comment: Do you want to update only the field currency without altering the person object? AFAIK When you use setState({ person.currency : 'euro' }) only the that field will be changed leaving the rest of the object as it was.

Comment: @Hanik So why are you using Redux? I'm really curious.

Comment: not only 1 field. it could be more ...

Comment: What's the type of `res.response.data.params` ? is it an object or an array ? Can you `console.log` it to share the structure ?

Comment: actually i wondering the react and i find the redux for manage the app like laravel middleware .

Comment: @dyo response.data.params is json object comes from lumen . i'm using lumen form backend api.

Comment: @Hanik First, I don't understand your 'manage the app' term. Second, Redux has nothing to do with Laravel's middleware, they are two completely separate things.

Comment: i want to tell it i use laravel normally but i want to make an app with react so i am newbie on this so i looked up like middleware in react but found nothing. i decided to use redux. it's working a middleware i think . am i wrong ?

Comment: @Hanik Please add an example of your `res` to the question so we can actually address your issue.

Comment: @ChrisG added an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) Operator:

```
this.setState({
  person: {...this.state.person, currency : 'euro'}
})
```

Comment: *`this._state_.person`

Comment: @YechielK what is it ?

Comment: this.setState( (prevState, props) => ({
  person: {...this.state.person, /* it must be a neted object here */}
}))

i use like above but not working. got this error "Unexpected token ... "

Comment: i added transform-object-rest-spread with npm i --save-dev transform-object-rest-spread and it works :) . thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need forEach. Assuming that in response will be something like this - { currency: 'usd', currency_sign: '$' } - you can just write

```
this.setState(person: res.response.data.params);
```

It will affect only the values what is inside response.

Comment: response params not comes like your writing so comes in array first argument like currency => [ 'euro ' ] . ok ?

Comment: Can you show what exactly you receive in res.response.data.params ?